# Composition of little-oh notation

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, analysis, approximation

I am fairly new to the use of little-oh notation and have come across many of the nice properties related to the use of this notation online. One that I am struggling to come across is how one may be able to simply expressions with little-oh notation when we are considering compositions. The problem that I am interested in is the following:

Given $o(f(o(n)))$ is there any way in which one might be able to simplify this expression for particular choices of the function $f$. In particular, what could one say about the expression $o(e^{o(n)})$? Can any simplifications to this be made?

I thought one could write
$$o(e^{o(n)})=o(1+o(n)+\frac{o(n)^2}{2!}+\cdots)=o(1)+o(n)+\cdots$$
but I am not entirely sure how may one simplify this?

Comment: Do not try to simplify an infinite series of $o$ terms.  Another remark.  $o(e^n)$ and $e^{o(n)}$ are different things.  For example, $e^{n/2}$ is not $e^{o(n)}$, but it is $o(e^n)$.  What would be your definition of $o(e^{o(n)})$ ?  There is no point simplifying something if we do not know its definition.